# Append column to another one row by row

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm writing code on android. I try to write a code which take data from one column and add to another column's string, do this for all database.

If it would be possible, i can add(append) column at one time.

Like this:

Before:

```
 A column | B column 
  string 1   string 2
```

After:

```
A column | B column 
 string 1   string 2+string 1
```

I'll try get strings from columns and update column but i can't do.

```
SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = dbHelper.getMydatabase();
        String query = new String( "select "+Database.KEY_COLUMN1+", "+Database.KEY_COLUMN'+ " from "+ Database.TABLE_NAME );
    cursor = mydatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
   while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String column1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.KEY_COLUMN1));
        String column2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.KEY_COLUMN2));
        column2=column1+colum2;
       mydatabase.execSQL("UPDATE "+Database.DATABASE_TABLE+" SET "+ Database.KEY_COLUMN2+ "="
               +column2);            
    }
    cursor.close();
```

I asked this question before but i updated my code and someone says i can't edit first message after asked a question. Sorry for that.

Comment: But you could have used the new code in *this* question ...

Answer (score 1):

Add a primary key to the table and then while updating the table after concatenation of the two columns put a WHERE clause using the primary key.

Based on your code, Database has no way to know which row you are trying to update.

Use this as your update query

```
mydatabase.execSQL("UPDATE "+Database.DATABASE_TABLE+" SET "+ Database.KEY_COLUMN2+ "="
           +column2 + " WHERE " + Database.KEY_ROW_ID + " = " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.KEY_ROW_ID))");
```

Comment: i used "_id" as primary key. I added  "+ " WHERE " + Database.KEY_ROW_ID + " = " + cursor.getColumnName(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.KEY_COLUMN2))" 

part but it doesn't work. Can i add whole coloumn to another like in excel?

Comment: Just edited my answer. Try using that query. you are using cursor.getColumnName where column value is required not the name